# IN Condition Issue in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to use multiple inputs in a procedure in `IN` condition. How can I do this?

Below is my query code.

```
Declare @iM_ID varchar(100)
set @iM_ID='20,22,24,25'
select @iM_ID
SELECT M.M_ID,    
SUM(CASE WHEN CT_ID=1     
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0 END) AS "Secret_Coupons",    
SUM(CASE WHEN CT_ID=2     
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0 END) AS "Hot_Coupons"    
FROM C_Master     
 INNER JOIN M_Master     
  ON C_Master.M_ID=M_Master.M_ID 
   and datediff(hh,getutcdate(),End_Datetime)>0  
   and M_Master.M_ID in (@iM_ID)
GROUP BY M_Master.M_ID
```

Comment: It's giving conversion "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '20,22,24,25' to data type int."

Comment: You're basically asking SQL Server `M_Master.M_ID in ('20,22,24,25')` not `M_Master.M_ID in (20,22,24,25)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX)
Declare @iM_ID varchar(100)
SET @iM_ID='20,22,24,25'

SET @sql = 'SELECT M.M_ID,SUM(CASE WHEN CT_ID=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Secret_Coupons",    
                          SUM(CASE WHEN CT_ID=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Hot_Coupons"    
            FROM C_Master INNER JOIN M_Master ON C_Master.M_ID=M_Master.M_ID 
                          AND datediff(hh,getutcdate(),End_Datetime)>0 AND 
            M_Master.M_ID IN ( ' + @iM_ID + ')
GROUP BY M_Master.M_ID'    

EXECUTE @sql
```

Comment: Even after adding @iM_ID declare and set to your code, I get an error - The name -- your code here -- is not a valid identifier.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev How can you get error when you don't have his table structure

Comment: yes, I was hoping for a no table exists error. So 'not a valid identifier' means object does not exist ?

Comment: No actually the query is still giving conversion error.

Comment: Thanks Vignesh, The query formed properly with your suggestion but EXECUTE @sql is not working.